# Firebase + Spring Boot: Verificar token de inicio de seción de firebase y generar un nuevo token a partir de este

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, backend

Estoy creando una aplicación que usará la autenticación de firebase para acceder al backend.

Por lo que la aplicación iniciará sesión en el frontend con firebase authentication, dónde obtendrá el id_token, ese id_token lo enviara al backend (Spring Boot) dónde se verificará para poder acceder a los recursos de la api.

Mis preguntas son:

1. Ya que el token dura solo una hora, ¿El refresh token se realizaría en el back-end o en el front-end?
2. Si el método para hacer el refresh token se hace desde el backend ¿Cómo podría realizarlo en spring security?

De antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: El cliente que utiliza el token para acceder al recurso es necesariamente el responsable de hacer el `refresh token` si quiere seguir accediendo al servidor de recursos que tienes con `spring boot`. El servidor de recursos no tiene por qué tener esa responsabilidad, y de hecho, ni siquiera tiene que conocer del `refresh token`, eso sería hasta una vulnerabilidad. En otras palabras, eso debe hacerlo el `front-end` que programaste.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya me aclaraste las cosas para seguir con mi proyecto.